# How to add a carriage return (`&crarr;`) when overflow-wrap breaks a long word?

Tags: css

If setting `overflow-wrap` to `break-word`, long words that have to be broken are broken. How to add a carriage return (`&crarr;`) when overflow-wrap breaks a long word?

Note that `hyphens` is a solution for pure text. But in many cases, we are dealing with code snippets and other words that are not supposed to be hyphenated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible on CSS for now, but you can use JavaScript to append it. 
...even the popular `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is still battling for browser support.